# Clipboarding Firefox RSS Links

Tags: firefox, clipboard, rss

How can I copy the RSS link which is behind the [image: RSS symbol] button in the addressbar into the clipboard? Left-clicking allows me to subscribe to the Feed with Firefox and right-clicking brings up the toolbar menu.

Currently I work around that by copying the links from the HTML source, but that is somewhat inconvenient.

Comment: Right click "Copy link location" or "Copy Shoutcut" doesn't work ?

Comment: @UK: that's not an available option on the symbol in the addressbar.

Comment: You know you can customise what Firefox does when you click that button. You can add applications (desktop or web) to the drop down list on the subscribe page it opens, and use the checkbox on the page to always use that app if you never want to use anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found this [bookmarklet](http://dekstop.de/weblog/2006/03/feed_links_bookmarklet/) that shows a pop-up containig the page feed list, each feed is a regular hyperlink so you can right-click to copy the URL.

Answer (score 0):

D'oh!

Clicking on `Subscribe to 'Feed for ...'` in the left-click menu opens the feed in the current tab. Then I can copy the feed's address from the addressbar.

This kills the current tab's contents, so I'm still not completely satisfied with this solution.

Comment: There's no easy way, since the button might hide more than one RSS feed.

Comment: Middle click it to open it in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Normally that feed button is shown, when Firefox finds out a link in that page, that leads to an RSS feed. So your page should have a link or and image that has the RSS feed. Just go to that link and Right click "Copy link location" or "Copy Shortcut". For example, in this very page, you have a link to the RSS feed in the bottom right corner of the page with link title **"question feed"**. Try that. Hope that helps!

Comment: The question came up on a page that didn't provide a separate link in the body.